# Python string not in file read

Tags: python

I want to check if a string is already existent in a file and base on this check do something. In more detail every day the script is launched, is adding a line to a csv file with one of the field being the date.

```
import time
today_fmt = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
file = open('allowance.csv','a+')

var0 = today_fmt not in file.read()
var1 = '30/10/2017' not in file.read()
```

Where allowance.csv file looks like:

```
28/10/2017,26.7,774.31
29/10/2017,25.62,717.29
30/10/2017,26.57,717.29
```

In this case today_fmt holds '30/10/2017' but when I run the script (using Python3.4) both var0 and var1 are **true** and I don't understand where I'm wrong. I have also tried:

```
var0 = str(today_fmt) not in file.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you open file with a+ option, file pointer will be at the end of file.

```
import time 
today_fmt = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
file = open('allowance.csv','a+')
file.seek(0) # File pointer will be at the begining of file
var0 = today_fmt not in file.read() 
file.seek(0) # Seek again 
var1 = '30/10/2017' not in file.read()
```

Comment: That's the problem, i'll upvote if you provide the solution also also you should always do ;) (And a good explanation about why your answer should be the correct)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed Birbal's code to work correctly so I'm not clear when you said I'm not give the solution. Sorry if I don't understand your comment, I'm a bad English guy :(

Comment: You should explain also why your solution works. You have to justify what've you done. For example I would have suggested to open the file with 'r' to point the file to the start. Why your solution is better or why your solution works?
Also please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! So as I understand correctly I would need to change the file pointer at the beginning of the file every time I do a check. After file.read(), the pointer will be back at the end? Because later on I need to add more lines at the end of the file. That's why I opened the file with a+ because I need to read it and append from time to time.